# How to use PHP to communicate with one click deployed google cloud wordpress database

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

latest update:

How can i establish the connection between Local PHP script and Google cloud SQL databse?

==========================================================================

update:

I added external ip address of the website and the IPaddress of my PC to the google cloud instance authorization.
I want to write PHP code and use it to connect to the google cloud sql instance then develop the application locally(How can i do that?).For example, fetch data from the database. After the local development succeed. I will deploy it online.(External ip address of the website already added to google cloud instance authorization, so it should works fine?)

---

This is the first time i am using google cloud platform.

1. I have deployed the wordpress by "google click to deploy"
2. I pull the website from online to local, and use flywheel to develop it in local environment.
3. I wrote a custom PHP page. It can communicate with the database and display the data to the webpage in local environment(localhost).

The question: If i upload this page to google cloud environment. How can the PHP code communicate with the mysql on google cloud? where can i find the hostname, db name , mysql user and mysql password?

Comment: There is a guide you can follow in order to connect a Compute Engine instance to Cloud SQL. You can find it over here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine I would recommend you to use the Cloud Proxy instead of the IP addresses though, this way you can connect using a service account. You can follow this other guide in order to connect to Cloud SQL from your local computer: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

Comment: I have done the "connect a Compute Engine instance to Cloud SQL". How can i establish the connection between Local PHP script and Google cloud SQL?

Comment: From your local computer, you would need to use the proxy too. You can follow the guide over at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy